# Remove index.html from Hexo URL?

Tags: ejs, hexo

In Hexo how do I remove the index.html bit from **page.path**?

**My code:**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<%= config.url %>/<%= page.path %><% } %>">
```

**Rendered HTML:**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://yoursite.com/about/index.html">
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what's the final goal of this?

Comment: For SEO its good if the canonical URL is the same as the URL, I only get /index.html on pages but posts are fine.

Answer (score 1):

This [request](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/1306) is on the [roadmap for Hexo 4.0](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/2492). It hasn't been implemented yet (at the time of writing this answer).

In the issue above, sapegin gave a workaround using a custom helper:

```
hexo.extend.helper.register('page_url', function(path, options) {
    return this.url_for(path, options).replace(/index\.html$/, '');
});
```

If you place this helper in a file like `scripts/helpers.js`, you can then use it in your posts and pages:

```
<%= page_url(page.path) %>
```

It's not as nice as a built-in variable, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because pages need to place in subdirectory. It's looks like this:

```
source
  _posts
  ...
  about
    index.md
```

That's all. No need any helpers here.

P.S. You also can see [live example](https://theme-next.org) and [source code](https://github.com/theme-next/theme-next.org/tree/source/source) with this.